# Add comments in a verse environment

Tags: verse

I'm using the `verse` environment to write some biblical text. It's nice tool for that. Now, I need to write some comments on the right side (not in the margins) as comments for texts blocks. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english,brazil,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
    \pagestyle{fancy} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \onehalfspacing 
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm]{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 

\begin{document}

\newlength{\saveleftmargini} % define a temp variable for the original margin
\setlength{\saveleftmargini}{\leftmargini} % write the original margin in this variable
\setlength{\leftmargini}{5em} % set the left margin to zero
\setlength{\vleftskip}{2em} 
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Ces-choses, il (les) adressa, Jésus, et ayant levé ses yeux vers le ciel (cf.~11)}

\setlength{\vgap}{3.5em}
\verselinenumbersleft

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

\scriptsize
\flagverse{1}Ces-choses, il (les) adressa, Jésus, et ayant levé ses yeux vers le ciel (cf.~11,41), il dit:\\
Père, elle est venue, l'heure:\\
\vin glorifie ton Fils afin que le Fils te glorifie,\\
\flagverse{2}\vin \vin comme tu lui donnas pouvoir sur (=de) toute chair,\\
\vin \vin afin que tout ce que tu lui as donné,\\
\vin \vin il (le) leur donne: vie éternelle.\\

\flagverse{3}\vin \vin \vin Or ceci est l'éternelle vie:\\
\vin \vin \vin qu'ils te connaissent,\\
\vin \vin \vin toi, le seul véritable Dieu,\\
\vin \vin \vin et (celui) que tu envoyas: Jésus Christ.\\

\flagverse{4}\vin \vin Moi, toi, je (te) glorifiai sur la terre,\\
\vin \vin l'\oe uvre, (l') ayant-parachevée,\\
\vin \vin que tu m'as donnée afin que je (la) fasse;\\

\flagverse{5}\vin et maintenant glorifie-moi, toi,\\
Père, auprès de toi-même,\\
de la gloire que j'avais avant l'être du monde\\
auprès de toi.\\[30pt]

\flagverse{6}Je manifestai ton nom aux hommes\\
que tu me donnas du monde;\\
\vin à toi, ils étaient,\\
\vin \vin et-à-moi, tu les donnas,\\
\vin \vin et ta parole, ils l'ont gardée.\\[30pt]
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

I've manually added the red text to show what's the final result I'd like to have in the end.
[image: Exemple]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I introduce `\notate{}`, using the `tabto` package.  I `\llap`ed the notations.  If you prefer left alignment, you could `\rlap` them.  The tabbing location can also be adjusted.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english,brazil,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
    \pagestyle{fancy} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \onehalfspacing 
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm]{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{tabto,xcolor}
\newcommand\notate[1]{%
  \tabto*{.7\textwidth}%
  \smash{\llap{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}%
  \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\saveleftmargini} % define a temp variable for the original margin
\setlength{\saveleftmargini}{\leftmargini} % write the original margin in this variable
\setlength{\leftmargini}{5em} % set the left margin to zero
\setlength{\vleftskip}{2em} 
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Ces-choses, il (les) adressa, Jésus, et ayant levé ses yeux vers le ciel (cf.~11)}

\setlength{\vgap}{3.5em}
\verselinenumbersleft

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

\scriptsize
\flagverse{1}Ces-choses, il (les) adressa, Jésus, et ayant levé ses yeux vers le ciel (cf.~11,41), il dit:\\
Père, elle est venue, l'heure:\notate{A}\\
\vin glorifie ton Fils afin que le Fils te glorifie,\\
\flagverse{2}\vin \vin comme tu lui donnas pouvoir sur (=de) toute chair,\\
\vin \vin afin que tout ce que tu lui as donné,\\
\vin \vin il (le) leur donne: vie éternelle.\\

\flagverse{3}\vin \vin \vin Or ceci est l'éternelle vie:\\
\vin \vin \vin qu'ils te connaissent,\\
\vin \vin \vin toi, le seul véritable Dieu,\notate{B}\\
\vin \vin \vin et (celui) que tu envoyas: Jésus Christ.\\

\flagverse{4}\vin \vin Moi, toi, je (te) glorifiai sur la terre,\\
\vin \vin l'\oe uvre, (l') ayant-parachevée,\\
\vin \vin que tu m'as donnée afin que je (la) fasse;\\

\flagverse{5}\vin et maintenant glorifie-moi, toi,\\
Père, auprès de toi-même,\\
de la gloire que j'avais avant l'être du monde\notate{A'}\\
auprès de toi.\\[30pt]

\flagverse{6}Je manifestai ton nom aux hommes\\
que tu me donnas du monde;\\
\vin à toi, ils étaient,\\
\vin \vin et-à-moi, tu les donnas,\\
\vin \vin et ta parole, ils l'ont gardée.\\[30pt]
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\smash` in `\notate` allows you to change the font size without any ill effect on the verse lines.  Thus,

```
\newcommand\notate[1]{%
  \tabto*{.7\textwidth}%
  \smash{\llap{\textcolor{red}{\large#1}}}%
  \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
}
```

will produce

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A regular `\marginpar` would also work, with some adjustments in terms of the placement:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verse,xcolor}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english,brazil,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
  \pagestyle{fancy} 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{geometry} 
  \geometry{a4paper,top=1.5cm,left=3cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm}

\newcommand{\versefont}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\setversefont}[1]{\renewcommand{\versefont}{#1}}
\newcommand{\versecomment}[1]{% \versecomment{<stuff>}
  \marginpar{% Insert \marginpar
    \makebox[0pt][r]{% zero-width box that is right-aligned
      \footnotesize\versefont #1% Default font is \footnotesize\versefont
      \hspace{\dimexpr\textwidth-\versewidth+1em}}}}% Push content over to within \versewidth+1em

\begin{document}

\newlength{\saveleftmargini} % define a temp variable for the original margin
\setlength{\saveleftmargini}{\leftmargini} % write the original margin in this variable
\setlength{\leftmargini}{5em} % set the left margin to zero
\setlength{\vleftskip}{2em} 
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Ces-choses, il (les) adressa, Jésus, et ayant levé ses yeux vers le ciel (cf.~11)}

\setlength{\vgap}{3.5em}
\verselinenumbersleft

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

\scriptsize
\flagverse{1}Ces-choses, il (les) adressa, Jésus, et ayant levé ses yeux vers le ciel (cf.~11,41), il dit: \\
Père, elle est venue, l'heure: \versecomment{A} \\
\vin glorifie ton Fils afin que le Fils te glorifie, \\
\flagverse{2}\vin \vin comme tu lui donnas pouvoir sur (=de) toute chair, \\
\vin \vin afin que tout ce que tu lui as donné, \\
\vin \vin il (le) leur donne: vie éternelle. \\

\flagverse{3}\vin \vin \vin Or ceci est l'éternelle vie: \\
\vin \vin \vin qu'ils te connaissent, \\
\vin \vin \vin toi, le seul véritable Dieu, \setversefont{\color{blue}}\versecomment{B}\\
\vin \vin \vin et (celui) que tu envoyas: Jésus Christ. \\

\flagverse{4}\vin \vin Moi, toi, je (te) glorifiai sur la terre, \\
\vin \vin l'\oe uvre, (l') ayant-parachevée, \\
\vin \vin que tu m'as donnée afin que je (la) fasse; \\

\flagverse{5}\vin et maintenant glorifie-moi, toi, \\
Père, auprès de toi-même, \versecomment{A\rlap{$'$}} \\
de la gloire que j'avais avant l'être du monde \\
auprès de toi. \\[30pt]

\flagverse{6}Je manifestai ton nom aux hommes \\
que tu me donnas du monde; \\
\vin à toi, ils étaient, \\
\vin \vin et-à-moi, tu les donnas, \\
\vin \vin et ta parole, ils l'ont gardée. \\[30pt]
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

The above minimal example adds `\versecomment{<stuff>}` which sets the content in the margin but shoved over to the left to the boundary of `\versewidth`... plus 1em. You can adjust this placement, of course, in addition to setting the `\versecomment` font using `\setversefont` (default is `\footnotesize\color{red}`).